# How to arrange a 3d cymatics experiment?

Tags: waves, experimental-physics, acoustics

Various researchers have filmed levitating polystyrene using sound waves.

If i were to take 3 speakers and attempt to visualize the standing wave fields formed by the three speakers, how would i do that? Using smoke, polystyrene, perhaps even flour from the kitchen? Would cartesian axis sine waves even make standing waves at all?

Comment: Please credit in small me if you manage to film 3D cymatics using speakers and light particles, it's A.Stewart

Comment: You will need a waveform generator with variable phase (a PC with a sound card and some software will do) and sufficiently strong speakers and amplifiers. Thankfully you won't need high fidelity and cheap speakers with several hundred W power can be had for like $40 these days. Digital amplifiers are also very cheap.